# One time login redirect to password change page

Tags: users, redirection

In D7, How can i redirect the user when he/she use One time login. My target is after clicking one time login button user has to redirect to change password. Can any one help on this.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hook_form_alter can be used to add a custom redirect rule. Do it in your custom module.

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if ($form_id == 'user_pass_reset'){
        $form_state['redirect'] = array('path/to/redirect', array('param' => 'val'));
    }
}
```