# Can I by pass the one time login page that forces a use to click "log in"?

Tags: users, forms

I'd like to send a user to a specific page on their one time login.  I'd also like to not force them through presentation of the page that says :

```
This is a one-time login for USER and will expire on DATE.
Click on this button to log in to the site and change your password.
This login can only be used once. 
Log In
```

I understand  the redirection I want to do can be done on a form submission override on the Login button form. [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34732/one-time-login-redirect-to-password-change-page)

I'd like to achieve the redirection AND by pass the one time login page.

My intial though is that the onetime login page is essencial to the one time login process. Is that true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this: http://drupal.org/node/350634

You could try setting your own function for user_pass_reset: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_pass_reset/7

Comment: I think this a good suggestion the parameters of my project have changed so I don't have this requirement any-more, so I wont be taking the time to implement my own replacement for user_pass_rest function.